# Set colours in ggplot geom-bar stacked

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got a stacked bar graph and I want to change the default colours. It's way too varied, a bit of an eyesore. I preferably want the colours to run to a theme, say red thru blue.

This is what it looks like now: [image]

This is the core of the code:

```
ggplot(Sheff_derby_form, aes(x = Result)) + 
geom_bar(aes(y = ..count.., fill = Res_vs_f_team))
```

Among other things, I have tried adding:

```
+ scale_color_manual(values = "pal")
```

With "pal" being a palette chosen using choose_palette(), but nothing seems to override the garish colour palette that RStudio is giving me.

Any ideas, folks?

Comment: You need `scale_fill_xxx`

Comment: One example https://stackoverflow.com/a/52032491/786542

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, but I'll explain two :

Using a 'theme' with RCorlorBrewer, using scale_color_brewer insted of scale_color_manual :

```
ggplot2::ggplot(Sheff_derby_form, aes(x = Result)) + 
ggplot2::geom_bar(ggplot2::aes(y = ..count.., fill = Res_vs_f_team)) +
ggplot2::scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

Check the color schemes here - http://colorbrewer2.org/#type=qualitative&scheme=Dark2&n=6

---

The second solution, or the one that takes work :

Doing thing manually with :

```
ggplot2::ggplot(Sheff_derby_form, aes(x = Result)) + 
ggplot2::geom_bar(ggplot2::aes(y = ..count.., fill = Res_vs_f_team)) +
ggplot2::scale_colour_manual(values = c('Blades and draw' = 'green',
                                        'Blades and loss' = '#4286f4'))
```

You can use the color names or preferably hexadecimal color. 
Also, I'm not sure about the value names, that depends on your fill variable.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if "pal" is a palette in R , I have never used that but you can try using

```
ggplot(Sheff_derby_form, aes(x = Result)) + 
geom_bar(aes(y = ..count.., fill = Res_vs_f_team))
  scale_fill_viridis_d(option  = "plasma")
```

Since you are using `fill=Res_vs_f_team` you should modify the fill options using `scale_fill_viridis_d`.

Hope this helps

Karthik Suresh

Comment: It works in the sense that it changes the colour. Thanks.But it's not really the colours I want. Are there any things similar to Viridis that would provide eg a set of colours from red to blue?

Comment: I got closer to what I want with: scale_fill_brewer(palette = "RdBu")

Comment: I am not really sure , but I found a package which will help you generate the code required for the ggplot . Try this package : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/esquisse/readme/README.html