# How can I achieve this simple chart using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Assuming I have the following data in a dataframe called df1, how can I process it using `ggplot2` so that I get the following output (shown in figure 1 below)?

[image: figure 1]

df1 is shown below:

```
     Desc         Value
   Extremely       0.22
   Moderately      0.19
   Minimally       0.15
   Not at all      0.44
```

I also want the white separator as shown in figure 1.

Comment: Useful guide on grouped barplots using ggplot, might come in handy? https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/48-grouped-barplot-with-ggplot2/

Answer (score 1):

It should work with something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(Desc=c("Extremely", "Moderately", "Minimally", "Not at all"), Value = c(0.22,0.19,0.15,0.44), 
                 cat = c(1,1,0,0), x.axis = c(1,1,1,1))

ggplot(df, aes(x=x.axis, y=Value, fill = Desc)) +
  geom_col(colour="white") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(Value, "%")),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#ff7f00", "#ff7f00", "#377eb8", "#377eb8")) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  ylab(NULL) +
  xlab(NULL) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none") +
  annotate(geom = 'text', label = "Extremely", x = 0.5, y = 0.22, vjust = 0)+
  annotate(geom = 'text', label = "Moderately", x = 0.5, y = 0.535, vjust = 0)+
  annotate(geom = 'text', label = "Minimally", x = 0.5, y = 0.708, vjust = 0)+
  annotate(geom = 'text', label = "Not at all", x = 0.5, y = 0.89, vjust = 0)
```

[image]

Comment: also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52032323/r-how-to-make-single-stacked-bar-chart-in-ggplot2/52032491